# h:mm:ss for workout data in MS Excel for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, date-time, cell-format

I am trying to store my running data in an Excel spreadsheet, but Excel keeps formatting it as a date and time.  For instance, I enter in `30:00` for 30 minutes and 0 seconds, and Excel converts it to `1/1/1900 6:00:00 AM`.  I've looked around and everyone says doing `Format -> Custom -> [h]:mm:ss` should fix it, but it isn't working for me.  Is there something I'm missing?  I'm using MS Office for Mac 2011.

Comment: It is interpreting your entry as "30 hours" most likely. Try entering "0:30:00". Also there is a format to show actual time values (not flipping at 24h) but i cannot remember the precise format. It might be [H]:mm:ss (with a capital H), but not sure.

Comment: `h:mm:ss` gives hours module 24; `[h]:mm:ss` allows hours ≥ 24. It's the `[…]` that does it; capitalizing the `H` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

From within your spreadsheet select the cells, columns or rows you wish to format and hit <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> to bring up the Format Cells dialogue. From here, click on **Number** then **Time** in the category list. You probably want something like **00:00:00** so that you can format automatically for hours, minutes and seconds.

Now when you enter 30:15, it should format as 30 minutes and 15 seconds. You can also sum these numbers for totals, averages, etc. If that doesn't suit you, you can always go with a **Custom** format. I've used this one before with success. Just type in the values below in the **Type**

```
[h]:mm:ss
```

This should give you a minutes:seconds format by default with an option for hours. Note that if 3 numbers are used, the first number will be interpreted as hours.

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it still saves it as a date and time.

Comment: @AnnoyedExcelUser: check the edited post above. Hope this helps.